# How to deploy Container on Windows for Production?

Tags: docker-swarm, asp.net-4.5, docker-network, multiple-domains, docker-for-windows

I'm new to docker, have to deploy multiple asp.net container on Windows Docker Swarm.In developement mode I expose iis sites using ip and different port.

Now we're completed development side planned to deploy on production.

I have to point separate domain and subdomain for each container.

How can I deploy container on Windows Docker Swarm. Please help me

Comment: Only 2 container orchestrators are officially supported for Windows containers, they are swarm and service fabric. You probably want to stay with swarm. You would have to use external load balancer in this setup and expose ports on each node for your container.

Comment: Thanks Gegory. Can you share steps on how to setup external load balancer on Cloud Azure Windows VM

Comment: Just use standard Azure LB in front of your VMs. It's pretty straight forward. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview